# why application.yml doesn't work in my springboot

Tags: spring-boot-configuration

I am new to the springboot. I want to change the default port 8080 to 9001.

Under the below image, I added a applicaton.yml,

```
server:
  port: 9001
```

but it dosen't work. While I added in application.properties it works.

My problem is my applicaton.yml seems no any relation with my project, I don't know why.
[image]

applicaton.yml should be working the way application.properties

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "application");
  SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

I added :

```
System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "application");
```

in the TestApplication class, SpringBoot load application.yml file!

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "application");
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```